# Remove BitMap in default Wix Installation Packages Version 4

Tags: installation, wix, project, wix4

The WixUI dialog library includes default bitmaps for the background of the welcome and completion dialogs and at the top banner of the other dialogs. I don't want to include a Bitmap in my installation UI, I am trying to remove it by doing the following:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui">
  <Package Name="Installer" Manufacturer="TODO" Version="1.0.0.0">
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>
    <Feature Id="Main">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentsGroups" />
    </Feature>
    <ui:WixUI Id="WixUI_Mondo" InstallDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
  </Package>
 <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value=""/>
</Wix>
```

However that does not seem to work. Can someone help me. I am using Wix version 4.